# Is there a dojo equivalent of jQuery address?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dojo, url-routing

I'm trying to create an ajax app with dojo. Is there an equivalent or something similar like functionality to jQuery Address. I want to make ajax hash based url navigation like twitter, facebook, etc with dojo.

regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in `dojo.hash`, available since 1.4:

http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/hash.html